# Websocket - client doesn't receive data

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

I'm writing some app based on websockets (RFC 6455). Unfortunetly it looks like the client (testing on Chrome 18) doesn't receive data, but the server says it is sending...

Chrome doesn't say anything

Here are main server methods:

```
private function decode($payload) {
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;

    if ($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 8);
    } elseif ($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 14);
    } else {
        $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 6);
    }

    $text = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i % 4];
    }

    $text = base64_decode($text);
    return $text;
}

private function encode($text) {
    $text = base64_encode($text);
    // 0x1 text frame (FIN + opcode)
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if ($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCS', $b1, 126, $length);
    else 
        $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);

    return $header . $text;
} 

protected function process($user, $msg) {
    echo '<< '.$msg.N;
    if (empty($msg)) {
        $this->send($user->socket, $msg);
        return;
    }
}

protected function send($client, $msg) {
    $msg = $this->encode($msg);
    echo '>> '.$msg.N;
    socket_write($client, $msg, strlen($msg));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending a test message >125 bytes but <65536, your problem might be caused by a faulty format string to pack.  I think this one should be 'CCn' (your current code writes the 2 bytes of the length in the wrong order).

If that doesn't help, you could try some client-side logging:

- Does the onopen callback run to prove that the initial [handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4) completed successfully?
- Do the onerror or onclose callbacks run, either after connection or after your server sends its message?