# WebSocket Server PHP Chrome unexpected compressed frame

Tags: php, google-chrome, compression, websocket

After completing a successful handshake, I try to send a message to Chrome, according to the newest protocol. I send it unmasked, unencoded, in plain text, and **NOT** surrounded with `chr(0)` or `chr(255)`. The first message is sent just fine, Google Chrome does not close the connection (although it does not fire the `onmessage`-event, but when I send the second message, a `Received unexpected compressed frame`-error occurs and the connection is terminated. Why is that and how can I fix it?

EDIT: My guess is that I need to prepend some kind of opcode, like the text opcode `%x1` (whatever it means and however it is expressed in PHP) and append another opcode, for the message end.

EDIT: The weirdest of all things happened: I once again tried the code from the other question but deactivated base64-encoding:

```
private static function encode($text) {

    // $text = base64_encode($text);

    // 0x1 text frame (FIN + opcode)
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if ($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    else
        $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);

    return $header . $text;

}
```

And now it works?! Although the encoding should not have mattered, since it is after the description anyway. I won't complain, though.

Comment: The [data framing](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.2) section of the spec describes exactly how to prefix a message.  There is no opcode for message end - the prefix includes a note of the body length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-handshake messages are not sent as plain text.  See the [data framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2) section of the spec for details.  Or see a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805023/websocket-client-doesnt-receive-data) for ideas on how to write a php server.  (Note that the code in that question was posted because it didn't quite work.  You'll need to apply the change suggested in the answer.)

EDIT: See section 5.1 of the spec.  The client must mask its messages; the server must not mask messages it sends.  Can you try removing masking from your server?

Comment: The problem is, when I send the message masked according to the protocol, Chrome complains that the message MUST NOT be masked. In uppercase.

Comment: Incidentally, I did try the code from the questn you posted, with the suggested fix from the answer - among others. At no avail.

Comment: @arik-so I've updated my answer to cover this latest information.  If that doesn't help, can you post your handshake and message sending code please?