# Websocket does not receive messages

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, websocket

**Server side:**

```
<?php
  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
  socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 8000);
  socket_listen($socket);
  $client = socket_accept($socket);
  $handshake = socket_read($client, 1024);
  preg_match('/Sec-WebSocket-Key\: (.+?)\r\n/', $handshake, $accept);
  $accept = base64_encode(sha1("$accept[1]258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", true));
  $handshake = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
  $handshake .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
  $handshake .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
  $handshake .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $accept\r\n\r\n";
  socket_write($client, $handshake.chr(0), strlen($handshake.chr(0)));
  socket_write($client, 's'.chr(0));
  sleep(5);
  socket_close($client);
  socket_close($socket);
?>
```

**Client side:**

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000');
        socket.onopen = function() {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'socket open<br />';
        }
        socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'new msg: '+msg.data+'<br />';
        }
        socket.onclose = function() {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'socket close';
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get "socket open" and after 5 seconds "socket close". I don't get the "s" sent by the server.
Tried on Firefox and Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Messages between client and server are not plain text. See the [data framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) section of the protocol spec for details on how to encode/decode messages.

There are plenty of code snippets in other SO questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805023/websocket-client-doesnt-receive-data)) that might help get you started.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried and it doesn't work [link](http://pastebin.com/X6DJg3b0).

Comment: Can you try adding an onerror callback in your javascript to check that doesn't run?  You could also remove the base64_encode from your server-side send() but that'll presumably simplify the code but not help with your problem.

Comment: I can see the error on firebug: `The connection to ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ was interrupted while the page was loading.`. In GC's developer tools: `A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client.`. And after that error the socket is closed. *And the onerror is invoked when the error occurs.

Comment: That suggests the data you're sending has the top bit of its second byte set.  You could maybe try using 'c' as the format to pack() when length <= 125